# which GCD queue to put firebase operations in? swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

Which queue is the best to place firebase operations? Is it the background queue, the main queue, or does it depend on how heavy the operation is?

Comment: What Firebase product are you using? There are quite a few of them. Also: what specific part of an operation are you considering? For example, the network interaction between the client and the database server (whether Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore) already happen off the main thread, so you don't need GCD for those.

Comment: As of right now, I'm just using the database, authentication, and storage (for images).

Comment: Reserve the main queue for UI related tasks.

Comment: Alright, so background queue it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on how much work you're doing in Firebase.

You can start out doing everything on the main thread. If you notice your UI lagging, switch to a background queue, and wrap all of your UI calls in a Dispatch.async call to the main thread.